# Move the player only in 45° steps with Touchpad in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using a `touchpad` of the `Touchpad` class in LibGDX to move the player. But now I want that the player can only move in 8 specific directions depending on the position of the `knob` of the `touchpad` and not in each possible direction:

Up, Up-right, Right, Right-down, Down, Down-left, Left, Left-up. So the angle between these directions is 45°.

The current code for the movement is:

```
player.setX(player.getX() + touchpad.getKnobPercentX() * Constants.SPEED);
player.setY(player.getY() + touchpad.getKnobPercentY() * Constants.SPEED);
```

What do I have to change so that the player only moves in one of these eight directions? I suppose that I have to round the knob position but I don't know how to do that exactly.

Besides that, I would rather that the `knob` of the `touchpad` shouldn't move "smoothly" anymore but only "jumps" to one of these eight positions so that the player directly can see which direction is currently active.

Can anybody help me with this problem or is there another way to handle that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does knob percent returns from 0-100 or 0-1?

Comment: It's a value between -1 and 1 (if the knob is at the center, it's 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, took me like one hour to figure it out, so I hope it works for you!

```
float dx = touchpad.getKnobPercentX();
float dy = touchpad.getKnobPercentY();

int direction = Math.floor((Math.atan2(dy, dx) + Math.PI/8) / (2*Math.PI/8));
if (direction == 8) direction = 0;
double angle = direction * (Math.PI/4);

player.setX(player.getX() + Math.cos(angle) * Constants.SPEED);
player.setY(player.getY() + Math.sin(angle) * Constants.SPEED);
```

Basically it find the angle of the knob, and from it finds the direction (one of the eight). The direction is multiplied by 45 degrees `Math.PI/4` to get an angle corresponding to it.

Comment: Awesome, it work's perfectly for me too. Thank you!


Do you know a possibility how to change the knob behaviour so that it jumps in these 45°-steps as well?

Comment: No, you would have to be able to set the knob position on screen, that doesn't seem to be possible. Don't forget to accept! :)